# Undecorated JInternalFrame becomes decorated when viewed through Remote Desktop Sharing

Tags: java, swing, remote-desktop, jinternalframe

I’m facing a problem with `JInternalFrame` implementation. I have made the `JInternalFrame` undecorated, so that the title bar and border of the `JInternalFrame` gets removed. The problem occurs in the following scenario.

1. Execute the program in a Windows 7 machine.

   - At this point the `JInternalFrame` remains undecorated.
2. Access the Windows 7 machine using remote desktop sharing from
   another machine.

   - Now the title bar and border of the internal frame becomes visible.

This issue occurs only in Windows 7 machine, and not in Windows XP. You can access the Windows 7 machine using remote desktop sharing from another Windows 7 machine or Windows XP machine.

Also if you access the machine using remote desktop sharing first, and then execute the program, the `JInternalFrame` remains undecorated.

Steps to reproduce

Step 1: Execute the application in a Windows 7 machine.

Step 2: Access the Windows 7 machine using remote desktop sharing from another Windows 7 or Windows XP machine.

Step 3: Check the GUI of the application

Result :- The title bar and border of the undecorated `JInternalFrame` becomes visible.

If anyone has faced this issue or if anyone has a solution for this issue, kindly share your thoughts.

A sample code using which you can reproduce this issue is given below.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

/*
 * InternalFrameDemo.java requires:
 *   MyInternalFrame.java
 */
public class InternalFrameDemo extends JFrame
                               implements ActionListener {
    JDesktopPane desktop;

    public InternalFrameDemo() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        createFrame(); //create first "window"
        setContentPane(desktop);
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Set up the lone menu.
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Document");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        //Set up the first menu item.
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.setActionCommand("new");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        //Set up the second menu item.
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_Q, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.setActionCommand("quit");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        return menuBar;
    }

    //React to menu selections.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("new".equals(e.getActionCommand())) { //new
            createFrame();
        } else { //quit
            quit();
        }
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
    }

    //Quit the application.
    protected void quit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        InternalFrameDemo frame = new InternalFrameDemo();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

/* Used by InternalFrameDemo.java. */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("Document #" + (++openFrameCount),
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

        //...Create the GUI and put it in the window...

        //...Then set the window size or call pack...
        setSize(300,300);
        // Undecorating the internal frame
        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane =  
            (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) this.getUI()).  
            getNorthPane();  
        this.remove(titlePane);
        this.setBorder(null);
        //Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is, do you have to use an internal frame?  If it's undecorated, could you simple use a `JPanel` instead?

Comment: I have to use JInternalFrame itself. The application supports two modes. In one mode there will be only a single internal frame which is undecorated. In the other mode, there can be multiple internal frames, which are decorated.

Comment: Dupe of https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2430018&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Walter. I referred to your reply in the above link and the issue is fixed now.

Comment: If the issue is fixed now, someone (@WalterLaan or OP) please write an answer and accept that, for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put undecorated property as shared not .setUndecorated(true) for InternalFrame instances.

or try

```
JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("frame", false, false, false, false);
frame.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```